# How do I query posts custom relationship field and include parsed search term into loop and display results in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I'm parsing a search term from the URL in a search results page like so:

```
http://localhost:8888/domain/?s=Varilite%20Icon%20Mid&post_type=knowledge_hub
```

I need the search.php template file to query a ACF relationship custom field to see if the linked post title matches the parsed variable in the URL and display the results. Below is my code but it does not work as it only displays posts with the search term in the post titles. How do I get my query to also check the custom field? Bare in mind this tempalte file is also used for the default global search so needs to be flexible.

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    //'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type'        => 'knowledge_hub',
    'meta_query'    => array(
       array(
        'key'       => 'related_products',
        'value'     => '"'.get_search_query().'"',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE', 
       )
    ),
    );
    $relatedProductArticles = get_posts($args);

    if ( have_posts($relatedProductArticles) ) : 
        while ( have_posts($relatedProductArticles) ) : the_post($relatedProductArticles);
            ?>
            
          <article class="col-12 search-item mb-5">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', ['class' => 'w-100']); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="px-4">
                  <h2><a class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
           
    <?php
            
        endwhile;
    else : ?>

        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );?></h2>
        
      <?php endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: by default get_search_query is escaped, try
`'value'     => get_search_query(false)`

Comment: Sorry but this didn't have any affect that I can see

Comment: I found that `$_GET['s']` echo's the term into the array, but for some reason the query is not getting the custom field `related_products`.

Answer (score 0):

TRY using `$_GET`.

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    //'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type'        => 'knowledge_hub',
    'meta_query'    => array(
       array(
        'key'       => 'related_products',
        'value'     => $_GET['s'],
        'compare'   => 'LIKE', 
       )
    ),
    );
    $relatedProductArticles = get_posts($args);

    if ( have_posts($relatedProductArticles) ) : 
        while ( have_posts($relatedProductArticles) ) : the_post($relatedProductArticles);
            ?>
            
          <article class="col-12 search-item mb-5">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', ['class' => 'w-100']); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="px-4">
                  <h2><a class="" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
           
    <?php
            
        endwhile;
    else : ?>

        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );?></h2>
        
      <?php endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Ah you're right in that `$_GET['s']` echo's the term into the array, but for some reason teh query is not getting the custom field `related_products`

Comment: @Amesey Did you ever figure this out? What was the solution?

Comment: What do you store in `related_products` ?